# Automate upload and download files from shopify server via FTP

Tags: api, shopify

I am wondering if there is anyway I can automate upload and download files via FTP from Shopify API

Answer (score 1):

See here: [How can I get FTP access to my website?](http://docs.shopify.com/support/other/general-information/how-can-i-get-ftp-access-to-my-website)

> Since Shopify is a fully hosted service, we don't provide FTP access to your website.

And here: [Why doesn't Shopify allow for FTP access?](http://www.quora.com/Shopify/Why-doesnt-Shopify-allow-for-FTP-access)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is **no**. You cannot use FTP with the Shopify API. The Shopify API uses HTTP for transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a tool to make this possible.

You can use FTP to upload and download files from the Shopify API using this FTP Proxy.

https://github.com/sstur/shopify-ftp

This is open-source and free to use. Please submit any issues you find to the GitHub Issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the tool @sstur, unfortunately it didn't work, I've submitted issue though in Github, thanks

Comment: Thanks @ryan-s. I've not tried this software on Windows 10 (from the readme: "I have tested this only on Mac but it should work fine on Windows.") So it doesn't surprise me there could be an issue. I'll try to see if we can get this figured out on the Github issue you submitted.